# Use InfoGainLoss for class distances (entry values <0) instead of similarities

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm trying to perform a pixelwise multilabel based segmentation using the [InfoGainLoss](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1InfogainLossLayer.html#details) layer and have 2 classes which are relatively similar to each other. To now be able to discriminate between them, I would like to introduce negative distance values instead of positive similarity values at the corresponding positions in the infogain_matrix, so that the loss value for the pixels are proportional to P(true class) and antiproportional to P(similar class), ideally forcing a sharper discrimination between the classes.

However, afaik, in the current implementation of the InfoGainLoss, negative values in the infogain_mat would not result in the behaviour i want, but instead decrease the loss value by the absolute value of H(ln,k)*P(k). Anyone with more experience with the InfoGainLoss can confirm this? And if possible give suggestions on how to implement the behaviour I want?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: looking at the code of infogain loss layer, I don't see anything about `abs(H)`. Have you tried negative values?

Comment: Okay so I tried negative values and on my dataset they can be used for finetuning the network in a second step after initial training is done to increase the separation between the similar classes. However, training from scratch I didn't manage yet as there often loss went to -QINF due to the loss approaching -QINF for negative H(ln,k) and small P(k).